# How to view/open cPanel Email files with attachments?

Tags: email, cpanel

I have backed up the user mailbox from the FTP of our cPanel. How can I view the email files, I can open them in any browser, but it shows in text format and the file name is like "1558386587.M325365P25747.mysitehost.net,S=12422,W=12716_2,S"

Any free software to view these files?